# How to change the default hotkey for indicator-synapse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, luna, wingpanel, search

I have the default key combination of <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate the `indicator-synapse`. How can I change it to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>?

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done. Also, super+space would be problematic given it's the shortcut for slingshot.

Comment: In-fact I have changed the keyboard shortcut for slingshot to `Super`+`D` from keyboard settings under system settings. But I find no way to configure it for indicator-synapse

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using xdotool. xdotool lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc.

#### Step 1: Install xdotool.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

#### Step 2: Move your mouse over the synapse icon and get mouse location

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

You should get output like this

```
x:1117 y:24 screen:0 window:39845936
```

#### Step 3: Add keyboard shortcut for indicator

Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts.`

Click the + and enter the below command:

```
xdotool mousemove x y click 1 mousemove restore
```

Replace x and y with the values you got. Set the shortcut as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> Logout and Login again.